# Unable to generate and sign a JWT for GitHub app authentification with Quarkus & Smallrye jwt

Tags: java, jwt, quarkus, github-api, smallrye

I am trying to create an endpoint on my Quarkus API to collect data from different github repos in my GitHub Organization. (GitHub Enterprise)

I want to do so by authenticating to a GitHub app installed in my organization. I am following the guide on [quarkus.io](https://quarkus.io/guides/security-jwt).

I have the app's `privateKey.pem` file stored in the `resources` folder of my project, where I have also set up the path to the file in `application.properties` like so:

```
smallrye.jwt.sign.key.location=privateKey.pem
```

The method to generate the JWT looks like this:

### `TokenManager.java`

```
// imports

@RequestScoped
public class TokenManager {

  public String getJwt() {
    return Jwt
      .issuer("https://github.com/apps/appname")
      .issuedAt(Instant.now())
      .expiresAt(Instant.now().plusMillis(600000))
      .sign();
  }
}
```

The resulting string is used in the authorization header param of my api requests.

#### The error

Even though my editor doesn't seem to recognize the property `smallrye.jwt.sign.key.location` it is actually passing but the underlying error that I'm getting is

```
ERROR [org.jbo.res.rea.com.cor.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext] (executor-thread-0) Request failed: io.smallrye.jwt.build.JwtSignatureException: SRJWT05009:
at ....
at ....
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: SRJWT05028: Signing key can not be created from the loaded content
```

I am not sure what is causing this, and if my initial configuration is correct to begin with so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please check with an independent tool the private key can indeed be read from `privateKey.pem` ? If it is GitHub, it might be an `EdDsa` key, in which case you'd need to customize the algorithm (see https://quarkus.io/guides/security-jwt-build#smallrye-jwt-builder-configuration) or in the code with `Jwt.issuer(...).jws().algorithm(...)`. Note, `issuedAt` is not needed unless you'd like to be precise about some time in the past, etc - it will be added automatically. Issuer, expiry. can also be configured (see the page I linked to earlier)

Comment: If you'd like you can generate a test key pair and open a quarkus issue or discussion and I can have a look why the key can not be loaded. Or explain how can I get the same type of private key and I can try it...

Comment: By the way do you have the PEM file starting immediately with `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----` or does it have some text starting with `Bag Attributes` ? If it has `Bag Attributes` - remove it and it should work - and I'll fix it on our side to make sure `Bag Attributes` are not interfering

Comment: @SergeyBeryozkin Hi, thank you for your help. I found out that the issue was that the privateKey.pem downloaded from my GitHub app was in PKCS1 format not PKCS8, meaning the header and footer looked like this `BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY` instead of `BEGIN PRIVATE KEY` which is why I was getting the error.

Comment: However I still have an issue with actually authenticating with my GitHub app. I have successfully verified the JWT signature but I am still getting bad credentials on my api request so I will probably open a quarkus discussion for that. Unfortunately there is limited documentation for working with github apps.

Comment: Sure, I opened https://github.com/smallrye/smallrye-jwt/issues/701 (`BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY` should really work), and yeah please open a discussion, looks like you might need to add a few claims into a token, if the signature is sound then the only other cause is that the token is missing some required claims expected by GitHub

Comment: Hi again, no need to open the discussion anymore. The problem I encountered was actually more related to how GitHub authentication works. I was trying to access contents of repos by authenticating as a GitHub app, which is not possible. The only way to access repos and their contents is to authenticate as a GitHub app installation.

Comment: Sounds good. Sure. By the way, you may want to try to authenticate users via GitHub to Quarkus with `quarkus-oidc` and authorization code flow and `quarkus.oidc.provider=github` and then use Resteasy Reactive client to access Github repositories - Quarkus will take of propagating the code flow access token itself. If it can be of interest then please open a new discussion, cheers